# Not able to authenticate during sofware installation

Tags: software-center, software-installation, authentication, policykit

When I try to install a package through Software Centre, an authentication window pops up.

The authentication window [is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvNp8.jpg):

[image: screenshot showing authentication failure]

But the window disappears immediately and I am not able to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [policykit-1-gnome](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/policykit-1-gnome) [image: Install policykit-1-gnome]. Now everything is working fine.